# Clearing a C array to zero when passed as a member of a pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer

In C++ when I have a struct definitions

```
struct foo
{
    ...
};

struct bar
{
    foo FooData[10];
    ...
};
```

And I want to write a function

```
void Baz(bar *Bar)
{
    Bar->FooData = {};
}
```

I get an error (C3079 in Visual Studio Community 2013) "an initializer-list cannot be used as the right operand of this assignment operator."

Yet this syntax seems to work fine in a situation like

```
int Array[10];
Array = {};
...
```

Why does the previous example fail to compile?

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. Also, tag one language only please.

Comment: I'd add your last example should not compile, and doesn't compile with clang 3.5; blame visual studio for not being strict enough.

Comment: @paulsm4 or `*bar = Bar{}`. Depending on the language.

Comment: Given this is tagged as `c++`, I would prefer `std::fill` to `memset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question: you can use the "{}" when you define your array ... but not afterwards.

Regarding the problem, I'd recommend [memset](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/memset.3.html)

`memset(Bar->FooData, 0, sizeof (bar->FooData));`

If you wanted to allocate FooData dynamically, you could define your struct like this:

```
struct bar
{
    foo *FooData;
    ...
```

Comment: `sizeof Bar->Foodata`

Comment: That would end in tears if `foo` was not of trivial layout.

Comment: `#define CLEAR(T) memset(&(T),0, sizeof(T))`

Comment: In other words, all bets off if "foot" itself contains pointers.  True.  But memset is still the first - and best - tool to reach for if the data is contiguous.